# Jupyter: execute multiple long running bash commands in parallel

Tags: c#, bash, go, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I use Jupyter Notebook to prepare local dev environments etc pp. Until know I used it for minikube which works very well because of the detached executions of container.

Additional to that I wanted to use it for a "docker free" environment where all projects are executed directly via cmd. The problem is that commands such as

```
go run main.go
```

are not detachable.

This means if I have an environment based on 4 projects, I can not start all of them via Jupyter Notebook. The Cell would wait for completion of the above command.

I already tried a solution which is something like that

```
bash --rcfile $TMPFILE
```

where $TMPFILE contains the above command. But even this is blocking the kernel.

I know of an parallel plugin, but this is only designed for Python.

Any ideas on that?

I want to execute projects based on .net, Go and NodeJS

Comment: are you sure jupyter is the right development environment for your use case, to me it sounds you should look for other options.

Comment: for me it is not an development environment. It is a tool to simplify all the commands I need during the development. Yes of course I could write a big script, but in the jupyter notebook it is very good maintainable and adjustable

Comment: why don't you run commands in the back ground for example "go run main.go &", or make a program that runs the commands in parallel.

Comment: I forgot to mention that. I tried it but the process was not working as expected and the returned PID was not that one which was processing (binding to a port). This means I lost control over the application.